# Debian batch downgrade packages to whatever currently downloadable

Tags: debian, apt

I have a bunch of packages "enhanced" by some Debian repository. Now I've disabled that repo from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and I want to re-install all packages that were "enhanced" to... whatever is available. I can get the list of packages just fine using grep, but

```
apt-get install --reinstall \
  $(dpkg-query -Wf '${Version}\t${Package}\n' | grep SOMEREPO | awk '{print $2}' )
```

reports that those packages can't be downloaded. And of course they can't — not at their current version. `--reinstall --downgrade` is rejected by `apt`. It seems that the only way to downgrade is to name a specific version (which would require even more nasty scripting for a **batch** of packages).

Anything I'm overlooking? Maybe aptitude can do it?

*Update*: I know it can be done via [pinning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270755/apt-pinning-priority-restricted) (thanks so much, mods!), but really, that's not a solution. It's laborious, and *I don't care* about which specific source the downgrade comes from. I want to downgrade to whatever is available from the currently-enabled sources.

*Update 2*: I'm using a Debian-derivative (MX Linux), so downgrades could come from

- Debian buster
- `buster-backports`
- the distro-specific `https://mirrors.*/mx/MX-Packages/mx/repo/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin-priorities are the solution; add this either to `/etc/apt/preferences`, or to a new file under `/etc/apt/preferences.d`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

`apt upgrade` will install the latest version of any installed package that it knows about, even if it means downgrading. `apt` only knows about packages from the currently-configured repositories, after `apt update`, so this will have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, from the *do as you're told, Debian* department... After some furious scripting:

```
ps=$(for p in $(dpkg-query -Wf '${Version}\t${Package}\n' | grep REPO | awk '{print $2}'); do
  apt --quiet list $p | grep -v /now | grep / | awk '{print $1}' | head -1
done)
# this still leaves some /oldstable,oldstable broken versions
apt install --reinstall $(echo "$ps" | cut -f1 -d,)
```

Not that I recommend it; it's just annoying when the system gets in the way of simple tasks.